# Change date format and add the day

Tags: perl, date

I need help with changing the format of a date and adding the day. Right now the date is MMYY (0919) and I need it to be YYYY-MM-DD(2019-09-01) with the day always being 01. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the date is always in the 21st century then you can use a simple regex substitution, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

say convert_date('0919');

sub convert_date {
    (my $yyyymmdd = shift) =~ s/(\d\d)(\d\d)/20$2-$1-01/;
    $yyyymmdd;
}
```

#### output

```
2019-09-01
```

This may be abbreviated if you are running Perl v 5.14 or later, like this

```
sub convert_date {
    shift =~ s/(\d\d)(\d\d)/20$2-$1-01/r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use excellent https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime. It will be really effortless if you need to do further date calculation.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $mmyydd = '0919' . '01';
print DateTime::Format::Strptime
    ->new(pattern => '%m%y%d')
    ->parse_datetime($mmyydd)
    ->ymd;
```

output:
    2019-09-01

Comment: You don't need to concatenate the '01'. Just using the original '0919' with the strptime pattern `%m%y` will work fine.

Comment: Correct Dave. I am showing the point that if those two( '0919' and '01' ) values comes from two different variables then we can concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

No need for DateTime. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been included in the standard Perl distribution since 2007.

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E'say Time::Piece->strptime("0919", "%m%y")->ymd'
2019-09-01
```